# How to find a new column for a group using some data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have household as a group. in each household there are some data for each member. I need to find the cost of travel for members who travel by bus. the fare of pass 30-day is 84$ so for each day it is 2.8$ also this fee for student and people more than 60 years old is half. Since it is unlimited per trips I want to dived 2.8 by the number of trips of each person.If a person doesn't have any trip by bus it is zero.

here is an example:

```
     household     person      trip       mode       student     age
         1            1          1          car         1         23
         1            1          2           bus        1         23
         1            1          3           bus        1         23
         1            2          1          car         0         65
         1            2          2           walk       0         65
         1            2          3           bus        0         65
         2            1          1            bus       0         18
         2            1          2            bus       0         18
         2            2          1             walk     0          40
```

Out put

```
      household     person      trip       mode       student     age   Fare
         1            1          1          car         1         23    1.4/2
         1            1          2           bus        1         23   1.4/2
         1            1          3           bus        1         23   1.4/2
         1            2          1          car         0         65   1.4/1
         1            2          2           walk       0         65   1.4/1
         1            2          3           bus        0         65   1.4/1
         2            1          1            bus       0         18   2.8/2
         2            1          2            bus       0         18   2.8/2
         2            2          1             walk     0          40   0
```

The first person is student and has 2 trip by bus so the cost is 1.4/2, the second person has 1 trip by bus and is more than 65 years old. In the second family first person has 2 trip by bus but he is yang and not student so cost is 2.8/2 the last person has no trip by bus so 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr`. We group dataframe by `household` and `person` if the person is a `student` OR has `age > 60` we apply half `rate` and divide it by number of times `mode == "bus"`.

```
rate = 2.8
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(household, person) %>%
  mutate(Fare = case_when(any(student == 1 | age > 60) & any(mode == "bus") ~ 
                         (rate/2)/sum(mode == "bus"), 
                      any(mode == "bus") ~ rate/sum(mode == "bus"), 
                      TRUE ~ 0))

# household person  trip mode  student   age  Fare
#      <int>  <int> <int> <fct>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#1         1      1     1 car         1    23   0.7
#2         1      1     2 bus         1    23   0.7
#3         1      1     3 bus         1    23   0.7
#4         1      2     1 car         0    65   1.4
#5         1      2     2 walk        0    65   1.4
#6         1      2     3 bus         0    65   1.4
#7         2      1     1 bus         0    18   1.4
#8         2      1     2 bus         0    18   1.4
#9         2      2     1 walk        0    40     0
```

Comment: why I get I get inf for some?

Comment: @shere Can you try the updated code. I added an extra condition to check.